# Why a hook works different when extracted from component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Here's my component with a hook

```
const UserCreatePassword = () => {
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  
  const [hasValidLength, setValidLength] = useState(null);
  const [hasNumber, setNumber] = useState(null);
  const [hasUpperCase, setUpperCase] = useState(null);
  const [hasLowerCase, setLowerCase] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValidLength(password.length >= 8 && password.length < 25);
    setUpperCase(password.toLowerCase() !== password);
    setLowerCase(password.toUpperCase() !== password);
    setNumber(/\d/.test(password));

  }, [password]);


  const handleUsersInput = (e) => {
    setPassword(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
           ...
            <TextInput name="password" onChange={(e) => handleUsersInput(e)} value={password} />
           ...
  );
};
```

This works perfectly fine and does password validation on the user's input. Then my next step was to extract a custom hook from it.
Now I have:

```
// hook file
export default function usePasswordValidation(password = '', minLength = 8, maxLength = 25) {
  const [hasValidLength, setValidLength] = useState(null);
  const [hasNumber, setNumber] = useState(null);
  const [hasUpperCase, setUpperCase] = useState(null);
  const [hasLowerCase, setLowerCase] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValidLength(password.length >= minLength && password.length < maxLength);
    setUpperCase(password.toLowerCase() !== password);
    setLowerCase(password.toUpperCase() !== password);
    setNumber(/\d/.test(password));

  }, [password, minLength, maxLength]);

  return { hasValidLength, hasNumber, hasUpperCase, hasLowerCase };
}
```

```
//component file

const UserCreatePassword = () => {
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const {
    hasValidLength,
    hasNumber,
    hasUpperCase,
    hasLowerCase,
  } = usePasswordValidation(password);


  const handleUsersInput = (e) => {
    setPassword(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
           ...
            <TextInput name="password" onChange={(e) => handleUsersInput(e)} value={password} />
           ...
  );
};
```

Now when I have extracted the hook, it goes one step behind the users input. For example I type 't' it validates empty string, then I add `e` to it and it validates `t` and so on.

I know setState is an asynchronous process, but

1. I would expect extracted hook works same as one inside component
2. I can't call my `usePasswordValidation` hook inside a `useEffect` in component cause this will give me an err and probably against the pattern of using hooks. So what I'm supposed to do here?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see this behavior. https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-hook-password-validation-v0zxn It validates the initial empty string, and continues to validate on each character. I track both the validation booleans (shown in HTML) and the current string being validated (in the console).

Comment: @DaveNewton, huh, I tried this again and it worked for me now. I'm a bit confused, but I'm guessing this can be because I changed the dependencies list in my useEffect. Real code looked much more complicated than I have here, so it was in the truncated part.
Anyways thanks for looking into this, it pushed me to try it again!

Comment: Glad you worked it out :)